# R: Selecting string with lowest value (in separate key) by row in data frame

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame in R containing rows of SNPs that looks something like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
rs111   rs222   NA      NA
rs333   rs444   rs555   rs666
rs777   rs888   rs999   NA
```

and another data frame:

```
SNP    P value
RS111  0.21
RS222  0.02
RS333  0.80
RS444  0.55
RS555  0.10
RS666  0.07
RS777  0.99
RS888  0.33
RS999  0.45
```

I am trying to extract the SNP with the lowest P value from each row in the first data frame into a new column or list. The dimensions of the actual data frame are ~ 15,000 rows x 500 columns (including a lot of NAs in most rows). I initially tried to substitute the labels with the P values using apply for each row and then trying to substitute the label for the P value using the match function but was unable to get a similar matrix back and am sure that is not the best way to do this.

Does anyone have an idea of how better to do this? Thank you very much!

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1$Col_min = df1 %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  gather(var, SNP, -ID) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(SNP = tolower(SNP))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.min(P_value)) %>%
  pull(SNP)
```

If speed is a concern, here's another solution using `hashmap`, which is pretty fast. Basically, I am storing `df2` as a hash table, and extracting the element with the lowest `P_value` for each row in `df1` by indexing on the value returned from the hash table lookup:

```
library(hashmap)

lookup = hashmap(df2$SNP, df2$P_value)

df1$Col_min = apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[which.min(lookup[[toupper(x)]])])
```

**Result:**

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Col_min
1   rs111   rs222    <NA>    <NA>   rs222
2   rs333   rs444   rs555   rs666   rs666
3   rs777   rs888   rs999    <NA>   rs888
```

**Benchmarks:**

```
hash_func = function(){
  apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[which.min(lookup[[toupper(x)]])])
}

dplyr_func = function(){
  df1 %>%
    mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
    gather(var, SNP, -ID) %>%
    left_join(df2 %>% mutate(SNP = tolower(SNP))) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(which.min(P_value)) %>%
    pull(SNP)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(dplyr_func(), hash_func())

# Unit: microseconds
#         expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq      max neval
# dplyr_func() 16530.857 17780.660 20086.9777 19017.828 21500.2595 42734.06   100
#  hash_func()   153.561   177.641   311.2788   268.633   298.0425  5254.22   100
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = read.table(text = "Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
rs111   rs222   NA      NA
rs333   rs444   rs555   rs666
rs777   rs888   rs999   NA", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 = read.table(text = "SNP    P_value
RS111  0.21
                 RS222  0.02
                 RS333  0.80
                 RS444  0.55
                 RS555  0.10
                 RS666  0.07
                 RS777  0.99
                 RS888  0.33
                 RS999  0.45", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! The dplyr + tidyr solution worked great and seemed to be pretty fast actually even with the larger data frame

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my solution is the best in terms of memory and performance, but at least it is something that should work. Comments and suggestions are appreciated!

Suppose the matrix is called `mat` and the data.frame is called `df`. First define a function `find_min`:

```
find_min <- function(v){
  temp <- filter(df, tolower(SNP) %in% v) %>% filter(P_value == min(P_value))
  return(temp$SNP)
}
```

Then you could do

```
result <- apply(mat, 1, find_min)
```

This would give you a column of the SNPs with the smallest P value, evaluated at each row of `mat`.

Hope this helps.